# XGBoost multiclass categorical label encoding error

Tags: python, xgboost, one-hot-encoding, multiclass-classification

According to XGBoost documentations, Categorical Features are not supported. Hence I am trying to one-hot-encode my categorical labels using `pd.get_dummies()` functionality. However, when I create a `DMatrix` object below I get an error saying that I cannot have multiple columns for my label in DMatrix

```
features = pd.get_dummies(df_features)
labels = pd.get_dummies(df_labels)

train_features, test_features, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(features, labels,
                                                                                test_size=0.25,
                                                                                random_state=42)

dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(train_features,label=train_labels)
```

Error:

> ValueError: DataFrame for label cannot have multiple columns

How can this issue be resolved?

Comment: Check your `train_labels`, it has to be a pd.series or single dimensional array

Comment: one-hot-encoding via pd.get_dummies() does not return a series but rather a matrix of 0s and 1s

Comment: You cannot have a multidimensional label.. Check XGBoost docs

Comment: Ok I see, thanks. So the only work around would be to use ordinal label encoding but that imposes an order on my categories?

Comment: Check this library https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/

Comment: Or another alternative is a multilabel classifer https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. all i did was

`labels = pd.get_dummies(df_labels).values`

and it will transform into an array of numbers

```
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0]
])
```